# How to Add Multiple Indexes in a single listview String

Tags: android, android-studio

```
            theList.add(data.getString(0));
            theList.add(data.getString(1));
            theList.add(data.getString(2));
            theList.add(data.getString(3));
            theList.add(data.getString(4));
```

I want to add all these indexes as a single row

I have Tried follwing code but it didn`t worked

```
theList.add(data.getString(0),data.getString(1),data.getString(2),data.getString(3),data.getString(4));
```

This is the Full Code of my Class. What i am trying to do is take data from my sqlite database and show in list view.
By this following code i am getting values in different rows but i want them in a single row

```
package com.example.project;

import android.database.Cursor;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

/**
 * Created by Mitch on 2016-05-13.
 */
public class ViewListContents extends AppCompatActivity {

    DBHelper myDB;
    User user;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.viewlistcontents_layout);

        ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);
        myDB = new DBHelper(this);

        //populate an ArrayList<String> from the database and then view it
        ArrayList<String> theList = new ArrayList<>();
        Cursor data = myDB.viewbuses();
        if(data.getCount() == 0){
            Toast.makeText(this, "There are no contents in this list!",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }else{
            while(data.moveToNext()) {
                
                theList.add(data.getString(0));
                theList.add(data.getString(1));
                theList.add(data.getString(2));
                theList.add(data.getString(3));
                theList.add(data.getString(4));
                theList.add("");


                ListAdapter listAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,theList);
                listView.setAdapter(listAdapter);
            }
        }


    }
}
```

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Probably concatenate the strings ?

Comment: Wow! It Worked `theList.add(data.getString(0)+data.getString(1)+data.getString(2)
                +data.getString(3)+data.getString(4));`
But Now the Problem is There is no space between values. Any solution for it?

Comment: You can add spaces `theList.add(data.getString(0) + "   " + data.getString(1) ...` but normally avoid `+` and use `.concat()` method

Comment: Amazing! Thanks a lot brother
It really Helped a lot :)

Answer (score 0):

**This is How I Resolved It**
First of All Thanks to **Mr. Zain** He Helped me to get it done.

I Concatenated Strings and it worked.
I wanted to Give space Between Values so this is how I did it.

```
theList.add(data.getString(0)+"    "+data.getString(1)+"    "
           +data.getString(2)+"    " +data.getString(3)+"    "+data.getString(4));
```

A Good Practice is to add .Concat() instead of "+"

Thank You!

Answer (score 0):

I recommend using RecyclerView instead because it provides far more functionality than ListView. It also leads to better performance. You will have to extend RecyclerView.Adapter and RecyclerView.ViewHolder as shown below.

- MyAdapter is similar to ArrayAdapter. It connects the RecyclerView to our data.
- MyDataViewHolder stores all the views for a single item in the list. In our case that is a single TextView, but it could be more.

```
public class MyAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MyAdapter.MyDataViewHolder> {
    private List<String> mList;
    public MyAdapter(List<String> list){
        this.mList = list;
    }

    protected static class MyDataViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
        protected TextView viewData;
        public MyDataViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            viewData = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.data);
        }
    }
}
```

You will also have to implement the following methods inside MyAdapter.

- onCreateViewHolder creates a MyDataViewHolder from xml.
- onBindViewHolder populates the MyDataViewHolder using our data.
- returns the number of elements shown.

```
    @Override
    public MyDataViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {
        View itemView = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.my_data, viewGroup, false);
        return new MyDataViewHolder(itemView);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(MyDataViewHolder viewHolder, int i) {
        String string = mList.get(i);
        viewHolder.viewData.setText(person.getLastName());
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return mList.size();
    }
```

Now use this inside your onCreate function.

```
mRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recyclerview);
mRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new GridLayoutManager(getActivity(), numberOfColumns));
mAdapter = new MyAdapter(mList);
mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
```